# Modify field at any level with circe-optics

Tags: circe

I am trying to transform the "model" field at any level with circe-optics and I'm having trouble in achieving this.

**Input:**

```
{
  "model":"ModelExample1",
  "test": {
    "model":"ModelExample2"
  }
}
```

**Expected Ouput:**

```
{
  "model":"AAAA-ModelExample1",
  "test": {
    "model":"AAAA-ModelExample2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circe optics do not provide a recursive modification function out of the box. However, you can make one:

```scala
import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._

val modifyModel: Json => Json = root.model.string.modify("AAAA-" + _)

def modifyAllModels(value: Json): Json =
    root.each.json.modify(modifyAllModels)(modifyModel(value))
```

The modification will be applied to all keys, not just `test` - if you don't want that, swap `each` for `test` in `modifyAllModels`.